# dstream parse JSON and save to textFile : SparkStreaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i have a Kakfa topic in which data is stored in a JSON format. I have written a spark streaming code and I want to save just the values from the Kafka topic to a file in HDFS .

This is how the data in my kafka topic looks like :

```scala
{"group_city":"\"Washington\"","group_country":"\"us\"","event_name":"\"Outdoor Afro Goes Ziplining\""}
```

Below, is the code I have written. When i print it, I get the parsed JSON, but my problem comes when i try to save just the values to text file.

```scala
val dstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc,preferredHosts,ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))

//___PRINTING RECORDS________
val output= dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreach { record =>
    val values = record.value()
    val tweet = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(values)
    val map:Map[String,String] = tweet.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
    map.foreach(p => println(p._2))
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the _problem_?

Comment: @philantrovert What i mean is , how can i parse the above dstream and just save the "values" to text file.

Comment: you can directly save that rdd to a file with `rdd.saveAsTextFile()` or convert to dataframe and write in a file in `Append` mode.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala yes Shankar you are right. I did that, but if i do what you suggested, it gives me a lot of other information. I just want to save the JSON values. For Eg, when i do rdd.saveAsTextFile(), this is what it gives :ConsumerRecord(topic = forMe, partition = 0, offset = 306, timestamp = 0, producer = null, key = null, value = {"group_city":"\"New York\"","group_country":"\"us\"","event_name":"\"Tools for Making Machine Learning more Reactive\""})
I just want the "value" fields from the above and then save them in a file

Answer (score 1):

You can save the rdd with `saveAsTextFile`, But since you only want to save the values you can convert to dataframe and write as a `csv`

```
dstream.foreachRDD(rawRDD => {

  // get the data 
  val rdd = rawRDD.map(_._2)

  rdd.saveAsTextFile("file path")

  //      or read the json String to dataframe and write as a csv

  spark.read.json(rdd).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).csv("path for output")
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Shankar, I appreciate your help, but I had already tried this. This is the error if i do what you suggested  :value _2 is not a member of org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]

Comment: can you share the screeshot? or can you try `val rdd = rawRDD.map(_.value())`

Comment: Thanks Shankar, i tried it and it gives me the values that i need. One more question though, I am doing this dstream.foreachRDD(rawRDD => {val rdd = rawRDD.map(_.value())rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/user/abc/test") . However, this only outputs the last kafka offset and after a while the file that was created, becomes empty. Any thoughts please?

Comment: This is because it runs in each batch interval and replaces with the new data. So it replaces with the empty data. You can filter the rdd and write only the nonempty ones. If you need to append the data you can use dataframe

Comment: Thanks again Shankar.